# В select выбираются не все значения из таблицы | SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Всех приветствую. Недавно начал работать с SQLAlchemy и PostgreSQL, столкнулся с такой проблемой

Исходный код:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, Table, Column, Integer,   String, MetaData, ForeignKey

meta = MetaData()

authors = Table('Authors', meta,
                Column('author_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                Column('name', String(250), nullable=False))

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:1234@localhost/sqlalchemy_tuts")
engine.connect()

conn = engine.connect()

meta.create_all(engine)

ins = authors.insert().values(name = 'Andrew')

conn.execute(ins)

ins = authors.insert().values(name = 'Mason')

conn.execute(ins)

query = authors.select()#.where(authors.c.name == 'Vasily')
result = conn.execute(query)
print(result.fetchall())
```

Компилятор выполняет код, и после мне выдаёт что-то вроде такого

```
[(12, 'Andrew'), (13, 'Mason')]
```

Но до этого было ещё 11 записей, которые мне тоже хотелось бы включить в список